# No IP after link outage

Tags: netplan

I have a 20.04 LTS server with two static addresses set.  The system applies the correct static IP addresses on boot up but if the physical link goes down/up for any reason (switch reboot for example) the interfaces come up but no IP is ever reapplied to the interfaces.  So I get an up interface with no IP address defined.  Running 'sudo netplan apply' applies the IP's for the interface back and they will stay there till the link goes down again for any reason.  This is an LTS server branch...WHAT IN THE HECK IS GOING ON???  These machines are headless....so if the network guys do some work...I'm screwed.

Why will it not apply an IP once link is back up???  I've been googling for the past 2 days and can't find any way to make it work correctly.  I'm I hitting a bug or something?

Comment: Ok, Netplan is a royal piece of shit...seriously.  Right after I ask this question I find the answer.  I am in the process of setting up this server and I have a gateway set for the interface but that gateway isn't alive since it is in testing.  Since it could not "see" the gateway...it would not apply the IP info.  What kinda of stupid crap is this.  Just apply the damn interface IP and stop trying to see if it is really working or not...........

Comment: Your description sounds like you specified an IP address that was not valid.  The good news is that your system is doing exactly what you've instructed it to do, so this is not a bug; it is an error in your configuration.

Comment: Welcome! Let me suggest using this neat [netplan examples documentation](https://netplan.io/examples/) by Canonical. It is a great documentation website for your overall needs. It covers almost your everyday needs. I can understand your frustration, it was somewhat hard for me as well to get used to this innovative tool after so many years of using other network administration tools - but netplan does a good work overall.